# MySQL and Java (JDBC) connectivity error: ACCESS DENIED FOR USER

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to write a Java application that connects to a MySQL database. The OS I am using is Linux Mint (in case it might be relevant for my problem) and I downloaded the JDBC driver for indipendent platform from the official site (I am using `mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar`).
My java code is this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Driver{
 public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            // 1) GET CONNECTION
            //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name", "user", "pass");

            // 2) CREATE STATEMENT
            Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            // 3) EXECUTE SQL QUERY
            ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ARENA");

            // 4) PROCESS THE RESULT SET
            while (myRs.next()){
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("Nome_Arena") + myRs.getString("Stato") 
                + myRs.getString("Citta") + myRs.getInt("N_posti") );
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

where, precisely, I substituted in line

`Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Wrestling", "user", "pass");`

the following things:

`db_name` with the real name of my database;

`user` with a real username (I tried EVERY username, included root. Same problem).

`pass` with the corresponding user password (precisely, I typed the passwords I set in MySQL at the first launch of the software when I installed it, but since they weren't working I even tried to use the passwords of Linux accounts, but it didn't work either)

From terminal I type this:

```
javac -classpath .:mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar Driver.java
java -classpath .:mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar Driver
```

and I get the following ERROR MESSAGE:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:22)
```

I already looked for possible solutions online, and I tried the following things:

1) I tried to  set permissions (in case something was wrong) for both root and the other user I have on the system:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

2) I tried to view all grants on the db:

```
SHOW GRANTS;                       (I was logged as root)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'           |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@%                                    |      (is it normal this @% I got?)
+------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'%'                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name`.* TO 'user'@'%'    |
+------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

3) someone in another post suggested to put the 3 strings (url, username and password) that are arguments of the connection in separated variables and calling the method passing thos variables as arguments, but didn't work.

I tried to be as much detailed as I could, exposing my problem. 
What can I do guys? I really spent hours trying to fix this, I have no idea what I could try next.

Comment: Have you set any password for the mysql users ?
Like "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'".
Also, are you sure the mysql port is default ? Should be 3306

Comment: Did you execute `flush privileges`?

Comment: Thanks for the advices guys, but I finally found the solution! It was something related to passwords/users. I noticed (from the list of users in mysql) that I had to identical usernames but one having as host "localhost", while the other "%". I tried a few things, and with the new user I created it worked. Maybe I was inserting the wrong anwser (but I am still not sure, cause I wrote all my passwords months ago in a file, and I didn't change any password since then). 

My app is now working correctly. Thanks anyway :)